# Ubuntu boot menu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multiboot

I recently installed ubuntu next to windows. When starting up, a multi boot menu from Ubuntu popped up. Now I had to reinstall Windows and the multi boot menu is gone. Only windows starts up. Is there a way to reinstall this Ubuntu menu? (there were multiple options to start Ubuntu, like safe mode, ... and off course Windows).

Comment: non programming questions should go to superuser.com

Comment: I'll try to keep that in mind in the future. I do wonder sometimes if guys like you just go and search all the stackoverflow questions to edit tags, the body, whether it shouldn't belong to superuser or any or the other 3000 alternatives... no offense. Maybe they should just add a dropdown to mark the question as either programming related, server related, installation related, configuration related, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that this happens is because windows installs its own bootloader after it is installed. You need to reset the ubuntu bootloader (GRUB) you can do this with an ubuntu livecd - see [this link](http://www.thpc.info/how/reinstall_grub.html)